# Saving the position of the sidebar with local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need help on using the local storage. It is necessary for the browser to remember the user action when minimizing / deploying the sidebar.

Script sidebar

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

All code [codepen](https://codepen.io/yuyazz/pen/pvbEax)

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage